# How can I download several PDF files from a website?

Tags: python, pdf, download

I have to access to this url: http://tinyurl.com/3ypvx24 and download every pdf file from 2003 to 2013. As you can see, when you click on a number the link takes you to the number issue and then you have to click on every paper to go to another url to finally download the pdf. Pretty annoying.

Can I do this in an easier way?

I've found out that just by this url: /REIS/jsp/REIS.jsp?opcion=articulo&ktitulo=1967&autor= I can access to the last url which contains the pdf by just changing the number (1967 in the example).

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the library urllib2, pycurl, or mechanize to automate this process. Its a long process and you have to write this by yourself :-)

Try Google for the libraries and check how they are being used from a Python code.